# Read identity server's settings XML for custom parameter

Tags: identity-server

In the identity server HTML files there's an identityServer.xml file at C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SI\sitecore\Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityServer\Config. I've modified this file in the past for the SHA512 setup and the cookie timeout, but I was wondering about applying a custom tag for a role, similar to what's in the CMS' web.config. Adding a node to the XML is no problem, of course, but I didn't know if there was a class already to read the setting from there, or if there was an easy (read: done in the view) way to access that role. Basically I'd like to set it so I can add the custom environment variable and pick up styles as needed for the login screen (to do similar to the environment styler tricks that worked throughout in 8.x).